# Syntax to create a Windows Service

Tags: windows, service, cmd

I have two folders 'C:\Apps-A\' and 'C:\Apps-B\', both need the same service installed.

It is already installed in Folder 'B' but NOT 'A'. (Was deleted a while ago and needs to be installed again)

Path to the running executable is 'C:\Apps-B\Windows Service\ConvertService.exe'

I am running the following sc create but it doesnt seem to work..

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc create "CS" binpath="C:\Apps-B\Windows Service\ConvertService.exe" start= auto
```

please help with correct syntax, When I run it, I get the usage instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved now, looks like with sc you need to make sure there is a space after the equal sign (binpath)

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc create "CS" binpath= "C:\Apps-B\Windows Service\ConvertService.exe" start= auto
```